# Error is Method is not visible: void monolyObjectRegulationListViewController.MonolyObjectRegulation.<init>(MonolyObjectRegulation__c)

Tags: apex

```java
    @isTest static void saveObjectRegulationTest() {
    Test.startTest();

    MonolyObjectRegulation__c testSObject = new MonolyObjectRegulation__c();
    testSObject.Name = 'Contact';
    testSObject.ObjectName__c = 'Contact';
    testSObject.ObjectType__c = 'Standard Object';
    testSObject.IsRegulated__c = true;
    monolyObjectRegulationListViewController.MonolyObjectRegulation objectToTest = new monolyObjectRegulationListViewController.MonolyObjectRegulation(testSObject);

    monolyObjectRegulationListViewController.ObjectRegulationInfo response = monolyObjectRegulationListViewController.saveObjectRegulation(
      JSON.serialize(objectToTest)
    );

    Test.stopTest();}
```

Class:

```java
  public class MonolyObjectRegulation {
    @AuraEnabled
    public string id;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string name;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string objectName;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string objectType;
    @AuraEnabled
    public string description;
    @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime lastModifiedDate;
    @AuraEnabled
    public Boolean isRegulated;
    MonolyObjectRegulation(MonolyObjectRegulation__c record) {
      this.id = record.Id;
      this.name = record.Name;
      this.objectName = record.ObjectName__c;
      this.objectType = record.ObjectType__c;
      this.description = record.Description__c;
      this.lastModifiedDate = record.LastModifiedDate__c;
      this.isRegulated = record.IsRegulated__c;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Access Modifier](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) is not specified, it's `private` by default.

You have 2 options here:

1. Make constructor public.

```java
public MonolyObjectRegulation(MonolyObjectRegulation__c record) {
 ...
}
```

2. Add [`TestVisible`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testvisible.htm) to your private constuctor.

```java
@TestVisible
MonolyObjectRegulation(MonolyObjectRegulation__c record) {
 ...
}
```